# Call an MVC controller action from a link in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I need to process some fees with a payment provider. I have a workflow where users select different programs and I calculate the fees. At the point of payment I have view where I generate a URL which the user clicks and goes to the payment gateway. The link has some JSON pairs needed for the gateway. However, when the user clicks the link, I want to create a new record in a transaction table with a UserId and a TransactionId so I can keep track of the transaction after it is returned to me by the payment gateway.

So in my view I have something like this (simplified):

```
{
    int TotalFees = (some fee calculation)
    string url = "{my JSON string goes here}";
    <a href="https://xyz.com/PayNow?paymentData=@url">Pay By Credit Card/e-Check ($@TotalFees).</a>
}
```

note: xyz.com is the external payment site.

I created an action method in a controller, but how do I call this controller from my link click given that I am posting to another site? How can I intercept the user clicking on external link and call a controller? Should I do this Javascript using a button and redirect to the payment provider from within that method?

The other approach would be to do the entire fee calculation in the controller and not the view, but that has issues since I want to collect user input on the view to calculate the fees to be charged.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do an html actionlink to your controller rather than posting directly to the end Site.  Then in your controller action do the post?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am trying to figure out how to pass some values from the previous view to my controller and then post to the external site.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different design. It seems it would make sense to create the transaction object/data in advance and/or attach it to whatever object you are using to build up the order during the ordering workflow. You could then manage its data/state after the order is completed (and having a transaction in some sort of pending state would be good since the payment may not actually be completed). Simple and clean. It seems you're in danger of putting business logic in your view the way you're going now, especially if you do the fee calculation there.

Comment: I agree with you. Initially I had wanted to track the transaction (give it an ID etc) earlier on and give it a pending flag. But I thought if users look at the fees and hit the back button the transaction would be orphaned and I wanted to avoid that. I guess there is no way to avoid it. Thanks.